# c program in eclipse, first printf function is not showing in console, after i entered 2 values it is showing 2 printf out in same line

Tags: c, eclipse

[image: c programming in eclipse]

I was doing c program in eclipse, first printf function is not showing in console, after I entered 2 values it is showing 2 printf out in same line, how to clear this problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    int a,b,c;

    printf("enter two  numbers");

    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    c=a+b;

    printf("total is %d",c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This is my code

Comment: It's probably some buffering issue, add the line `fflush(stdout);` after the 1st printf.

Comment: yes thank you adding fflush(stdout); after the first print worked for me

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be that the print isn't flushed to the terminal.
when you use printf you actually are writing to a buffer that will be flushed to the terminal after one of the following:

1. the buffer is full
2. enough time has passed
3. you ended your print with '\n'
4. you give a flush command

I recommend just finishing your print with the '\n'

```
printf("enter two  numbers\n");
```

Comment: i tried adding '\n' now the output is showing similar but a slight diffrence  :

-enter two numbers
-answer is 30                                                                                                                                    before it was in the same line now it is in 2 lines